# How to add a new model in tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I know there could be more than one model running at a time, which you can specify in a config file, as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/452).

In my case, I want to start the server with `model_A`, `model_B` and `model_C`, and in a future, add a new arbitrary `model_D` **without restarting the server** (since I don't want to interrupt the service for models A, B and C).

Is there a way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

The following commit adds this functionality (and should be in TensorFlow Serving 1.7.0 and higher:

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/79d3354cd8a408fb981670512d661c2b7e89f5bf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the commit and [the PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/pull/774), that is already merged. However, at least for me, it's not straightforward from what I've read, how should I use it. Can you give an usage example?