# How to push a new model to tensorflow-serving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I need a way to use **Python 3** to push newly trained models to a deployed container running **tensorflow-serving**.

Found the tfx package (https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/pusher) but it only works with **python 2.7** .

Also found this question that points out that this functionality exists:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052187/how-to-add-a-new-model-in-tensorflow-serving

But I'm still lacking a good guide on how to deploy a new model using **Python 3**.

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735141/2912207

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Model and have saved it in the path, "/usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/export".

Then, I have committed it to the Tensorflow Serving Docker Container and  inferenced that Model and got the results.

Commands to be run in Command Prompt, for achieving what is explained above is shown below:

```
sudo docker run -d --name sb tensorflow/serving

sudo docker cp /usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/export sb:/models/export

sudo docker commit --change "ENV MODEL_NAME export" sb rak_iris_container

sudo docker kill sb

sudo docker pull tensorflow/serving

sudo docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/export,target=/models/export -e MODEL_NAME=export -t tensorflow/serving &

saved_model_cli show --dir /usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/1554294699 --all

curl -d '{"examples":[{"SepalLength":[5.1],"SepalWidth":[3.3],"PetalLength":[1.7],"PetalWidth":[0.5]}]}' \
  -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/export:classify
```

Output of above inference is

```
{
    "results": [[["0", 0.998091], ["1", 0.00190929], ["2", 1.46236e-08]]
    ]
}
```

Model is saved using the code mentioned below:

```
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(my_feature_columns)
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
export_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel('export', serving_input_receiver_fn)
print('Exported to {}'.format(export_dir))
```

Output of above command is:

Exported to b'/usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/1554980806'