# Hot load of models into tensorflow serving container

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I know how to load a model into a container and also I know that we can create a static config file and when we run a tensorflow serving container pass it to the container and later use one the models inside that config files but I want to know if there is any way to hot load a completely new model (not a newer version of the previous model) into a running tensorflow serving container. What I mean is we run the container with model-A and later we load model-B into the container and use it, can we do this? If yes how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can.

First you need to copy the new model files to `model_base_path` you specified when launching the tf serve, so that the server can see the new model. The directory layout is usually this: $MODEL_BASE_PATH/$model_a/$version_a/* and $MODEL_BASE_PATH/$model_b/$version_b/*

Then you need to refresh the tf serve with a new model_config_file that includes the entry for the new model. See [here on how to add entries to the model config file](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config). To make the server take in the new config, there are two ways to do it:

1. save the new config file and restart the tf serve.
2. reload the new model config on the fly without restarting the tf serve. This service is defined in [model_service.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/model_service.proto#L22) as HandleReloadConfigRequest, but the service's [REST api](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) does not seem to support it, so you need to rely on the gRPC API. Sadly the [Python client for gRPC](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/96a716ca31f753b0c3efc1ef60779b77f5c60845/tensorflow_serving/apis/model_service_pb2_grpc.py#L68) seems unimplemented. I managed to generate Java client code from protobuf files, but it is quite complex. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717880/inferencing-with-tensorflow-serving-using-java) explains how to generate Java client code for doing gRPC inferencing, and doing handleReloadConfigRequest() is very similar.

Comment: Correction - seem the Python client API does support HandleReloadConfigRequest(), here is a code example from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455066/2912207